# Mocked object not able to access class constants

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

I'm just starting to get my head around PHPUnit & mocked classes. I'm attempting to test a piece of code which gets a query object from a database object, then fetches data from this query. So I'm trying to mock out the functionality of these database objects so they always returns a known set of data.

My client code is running the following line:

```
    $result = $query->fetch(db::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

When I try and run the test, I'm given the following error: `Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'FETCH_ASSOC' in...... etc`

The code within the test that creates the mock objects is like this:

```
    /** dbQuery Mock Object */
    $this->dbQuery = $this->getMock('dbQuery', array('execute', 'fetch' ), array(), '', false);

    $this->dbQuery->expects($this->any())
                  ->method('execute')
                  ->will($this->returnValue(null));

    $this->dbQuery->expects($this->any())
                  ->method('fetch')
                  ->will($this->returnValue(null));


    /** db Mock Object */
    $this->dbro = $this->getMock('db', array('prepare'), array(), '', false);
    $this->dbro->expects($this->once())
        ->method('prepare')
        ->will($this->returnValue($this->dbQuery));
```

So my question is, how can I access the class constants of the mocked db object? OR, what exactly am I missing in the grand scheme of things?

Comment: Need to see your test, since you have created different mock objects.  The short answer is in the Mock'd class, the constant does not exist, since it is trying to use db::FETCH_ASSOC and you are not in the db anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getMock` could create object based on nonexistent class. In this case it would create two classes.

```
$dbro = $this->getMock('db', array('prepare'), array(), '', false);
```

If `db` class not defined `PHPUnit` create `db` class and `db_2528522f` (some hash). So new created class have no consts at all.

Are you sure that included all required files or your autoload works properly?

Comment: Thanks your comment helped me figure out what I was doing wrong. My code simply had not included the source file for my db object. I incorrectly assumed that PHPUnit would only let you create a mock class for classes that have been included.

Comment: JMac, not having to include your source file is precisely the reason for mocking! Imagine the number of source files you would have to include with a large application, just to make tests run. Or having to include that source file in EVERY test that mocks the DB :-(